# PHP Possible to build form elements after a selection is made?

Tags: php, jquery

I have a form with a select box that determines if a div is hidden or shown.  Each div has text boxes and a button.   Since my validation is validating ALL divs hidden or shown, is it possible IF a select option is selected PHP can echo the form picked? For example,  below I have

```
    <div id="1" class="colors" style="display:none">
      <input type="text" name="1">
      <button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button> 
    </div>
```

Is it possible to create an array to build the code above when that option is picked?  Same goes for the second hidden div -

```
   <div id="2" class="colors" style="display:none">
     <input type="text" name="1">
     <input type="text" name="2">
     <button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
```

This way only one form will be created at a time when a option is picked in the select box.   Is this possible? Is this a good idea? The original form will have more form elements.. this is just a sample.  Here's the code below.

```
<script>
  $(function() {
  $('#colorselector').change(function(){
            $('.colors').hide();
            $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
        });
    });
    </script>


   <form action="" onSubmit="return validateForm(this)" method="post" name="form">
    <select id="colorselector">
     <option selected></option>
     <option value="1">1</option>
     <option value="2">2</option>
     </select>

    <div id="1" class="colors" style="display:none">
     <input type="text" name="1">
     <button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button> 
    </div>
    <div id="2" class="colors" style="display:none">
     <input type="text" name="1">
     <input type="text" name="2">
     <button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
    </div></form>
```

If this is possible and a good idea, can you provide an example on how this can be accomplished?

Comment: Very possible. Go learn about how to make AJAX calls. You're already using jQuery, so using `$.ajax` should be very easy for you.

Comment: I don't want to use AJAX.  If I'm going to create an array to build a form why would I use AJAX?  Seems PHP would be more ideal....   Not sure why you even commented.... Not a lot going on where your located?

Comment: AJAX is not a language. It simply describes a protocol for JavaScript to speak with a server (in your case, a server running PHP). PHP does not run on the front-end. Once your PHP code has been executed the first time and the page has been served to the client, PHP can't do anything. The only way to continue using PHP without reloading the page is to make an AJAX request from the JavaScript to it. Again, please go read about AJAX.

Comment: Also, insulting people trying to help you generally isn't a good way to continue getting help on this site.

Comment: Telling me to go learn AJAX isn't helping.

Comment: I'm telling you it is literally **THE ONLY WAY** to do what you want. And there is nothing special about AJAX. You just need to learn about the jQuery `$.ajax` method and then learn about the PHP `$_REQUEST` super global.

Comment: I'm not saying I want to do what I'm saying.... I'm asking is this the only way since I'm having problems with validation.  Is there another way?

Comment: The only way that does not involve having all the forms hardcoded on the page already is to either have a generic JavaScript function that is able to generate forms based on input on the page, or, to make an AJAX call to your PHP which can serve the page. Assuming creating the form requires data not already on the page, the correct way to generate it is to make the AJAX call and have PHP echo back the full HTML of the form.